# Intermittent high GPU usage when idle on the desktop

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I don't usually monitor my GPU usage during idle time but happened to notice some high GPU resource usage in HWiNFO64 monitoring software. It is not constant but intermittent and I can't determine exactly what is causing it.

I'm seeing something cause a 63% gpu core load and near max core clock and memory clock speeds. My question is whether this would be normal for some background software to have to use such a high amount of GPU resources? I have the app Process Explorer but can't seem to get a breakdown of what apps are using exactly how much of the GPU.

Comment: Did you check the processes on your task manager? there are applications or processes that you usually close but still run on the background process.

Comment: There is something consuming high resources from the GPU as soon as I've done a clean boot, so I think it has to be a particular startup program or Google Chrome as that's all I'm usually using on the desktop or at least while I've noticed this anyway.

Comment: Probably its your network / internet connection resources. Try removing cookies / cache from your browsers. Maybe there are add-ins installed on your google chrome. Disable it but I suggest you remove it if some are useless.